# python , different result of code

Tags: python

Where is the mistake in my first function? I have this:

```
def fun(str):    
    for vowel in str:
        if vowel in 'aeiouAEIOU':
            return len(vowel)
```

---

```
def fun(str):
    return len([vowel for vowel in str if vowel in 'aeiouAEIOU'])

print fun("halloo")
```

The results for the two functions are different. I must return the number of vowels the string contains.

Comment: On a side note, I would not call the loop-variable `vowel`, as it isn't necessarily one. I'd go with `character` instead. Obviously that doesn't change anything about the problem itself, but there are plenty of answers to that effect already.

Answer (score 3):

In your first function you immediately return when you find a vowel, and you returned the length of that one vowel. The result is always either `1` (vowel found) or `None` (no vowel found).

If you wanted to count the number of vowels, you'd have to use a new variable to track that count:

```
def fun(str):
    count = 0
    for vowel in str:
        if vowel in 'aeiouAEIOU':
            count += 1
    return count
```

The second function produces a list of all the vowels first, then takes the length of that list. You could use:

```
def fun(str):
    return sum(1 for vowel in str if vowel in 'aeiouAEIOU')
```

to not even produce a list, just a vowel count.

Answer (score 2):

In this function, when you reach a vowel, you're returning the length of `vowel` (a single character) - which is always going to be `1` (or if it drops off the end of the function `None`):

```
def fun(str):    
    for vowel in str:
        if vowel in 'aeiouAEIOU':
            return len(vowel)
```

While in this one, you're building up a list of all vowels and taking the length:

```
def fun(str):
    return len([vowel for vowel in str if vowel in 'aeiouAEIOU'])
```

Note that `str` is a builtin type, it'd be better to call your parameter `text` to avoid any potential headaches (not necessarily in this function, but for future reference) in the future.

Ultimately, you can write this as (with a more descriptive name and parameter):

```
def vowel_count(text):
    return sum(1 for ch in text.lower() if ch in 'aeiou')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first code will `return 1` or `None` :

```
def fun(str):
  for vowel in str:
    if vowel in 'aeiouAEIOU':
      return len(vowel)

print fun('111') # return None
print fun('abc') # return 1
```

Your Second code will be ok to return the number of char(s) in vowel.

Answer (score 0):

Use `count` method of string. Time complexity is `O(N) * 5`

code:

```
def countVowel(input):
    input = input.lower()    
    count = input.count("a") + input.count("e") + input.count("i") +\
    input.count("o") + input.count("u") 
    return count

print "Result:- ", countVowel("halloo")
print "Result:- ", countVowel("halloo HELLOO A ")
```

output:

```
$ python test.py
Result:-  3
Result:-  7
```

---

By `collections` module. Time complexity is `O(N) * 5`

code:

```
import collections

def countVowel(input):
    input = input.lower()
    info = collections.Counter(input)  #`O(N) * 5` 
    count = info["a"] + info["e"] + info["i"] + info["o"] + info["u"]
    return count

print "Result:- ", countVowel("halloo")
print "Result:- ", countVowel("halloo HELLOO A ")
```

output:

```
$ python test.py
Result:-  3
Result:-  7
```

---

By regular expression

code:

```
import re

def countVowel(input):
    input = input.lower()
    count = len(re.findall("a|e|i|o|u", input))
    return count

print "Result:- ", countVowel("halloo")
print "Result:- ", countVowel("halloo HELLOO A ")
```

output:

```
$ python test.py
Result:-  3
Result:-  7
```

---

Time Complexity `O(N)*1`

code:

```
def countVowel(input):
    input = input.lower()
    count = 0
    for i in input:
        if "aeiou".__contains__(i):
            count += 1
    return count

print "Result:- ", countVowel("halloo")
print "Result:- ", countVowel("halloo HELLOO A ")
```

output:

```
$ python test.py
Result:-  3
Result:-  7
```

Comment: O(N) * 5 complexity - ouch!?

Comment: yes, just showing OP that this can be other way. So he can understand what `count` does..

Comment: From a complexity standpoint: Aren't both algorithms (the other one being testing each char if it is a vowel) `O(n)`? I mean, `n*5` is still `O(n)`